# Use same cookie for two websites on localhost

Tags: node.js, ajax, iis, cookies, identity

I have two websites running on localhost with different ports, one running on node and another on iis. I want to use same cookie to be authorized on ajax calls(we are exposing data on the iis site but it has authentication with identity ) How can i do that?

Comment: Cookies under the same domain should be accessible with no troubles. Check if it is being written as HttpOnly, Session or Secure cookies and you are trying to access it from the browser

Comment: It could be possible but you must handle when this cookies expired..

Comment: I am getting this error:
`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 ` 

The axios request is:
`client.get(url, { withCredentials: true });`   
I am setting on webconfig:
 `<customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080" />`